# Почему ADB не видит телефон

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Подключаю устройство и ADB его не находит, не знаю в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить? Драйвера установлены, искал пути решения в интернете, применял и не чего не помогло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Включите режим разработчика и отладку по usb в настройках своего телефона

Comment: вот красный цвет про "unable to connect...". вот это не есть хорошо. ищи ошибку связанную с этим. ну и как как сказали выше - "реж.разраба + отладка по usb". но этого красного сообщения не должно быть.

Comment: Либо включен проброс портов или что-то его блокирует